# Android. Размер видимой части Activity

Tags: android, java, activity

Необходимо получить размер видимой части `Activity`, что бы знать пропорции.

Размер экрана знаю как получить, но это не то, что нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

предположу, что под видимой частью подразумевается **[экран - статус бар, ширина]**

получить высоту статус бара можно таким образом:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() 
{ 
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    } 
    return result;
}
```

с остальным думаю справитесь